# How to identify database of Ether

Tags: ether

After reading wiki, I understand Ethereum is a programming platform to develop different blockchains.

However, there seems to be one Ether currency that is traded on exchanges.

How to identify that particular blockchain where Ether is used? Is it list of IP addresses of full nodes or other way?

P.S. I wonder if **ether** and **Ether** have different meaning?

Comment: There's only one Ethereum blockchain (if you discount the Test network). Ether is the currency used on that blockchain, and should be referred to as "ether" (lower-case "e") though I'd imagine lots of people aren't particularly strict about this.

Comment: @Richard Horrocks, means everybody makes their DAOs, etc. on one database? I cannot take Etherium code (is it open source?) and make my own private blockchain on Etherium tech? People are supposed to make their not related to each other applications using same shared ether supply?

Comment: OK, your question is clearer now. Yes, it's open source, and yes, you can implement your own private blockchain with its own currency. But the public blockchain uses ether. There's currently no way for the public chain to interact with private chains and their currencies.

Comment: @Richard Horrocks, thank you. Then I can make blockchain and declare it public. How current 'original' public blockchain is identified on the Internet?

Comment: Because that original blockchain comes from a particular 'genesis block', which is hardcoded on the ethereum client. Then, all the mainstream ethereum transaction history must reference that very first block. If you want to create another blockchain, you must start to pick another genesis block and start mining from it. However, this leads to a lesser network security, so I'm not sure why would you want to do that. But for sure you could (in fact the testnet is some sort of a parallel blockchain that currently exists).

Comment: @Sergeon, thank you. But how do I find the database? Only via downloading software from specific websites or there is more general ways?

Comment: I think you can just configure a node to be able to talk to other nodes that use a specific blockchain. I think that shouldn't be complicated: I'm pretty sure this is how the testnet blockchain works, just configuring specifically the datadir and some config files the ethereum node consumes. However, I don't have any experience on how to do this :-S. If you would want anyone to come to your network, you should publish your genesis block / config widely so everyone can configure its node to talk to your.